# React onClick attribute not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React class here, in which the `render()` method returns `button`s with onClick attribute.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var array = [];
        // var key = 1;
        for (let i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++) {
            // let subarray of state
            var row_ = [];
            for (let n = 0 ; n <= 2 ; n++) {
                // let cell of subarray
                row_.push(
                    <button
                        className='choiceButton'
                        row={i}
                        col={n}
                        ref={'button' + i + '_' + n}
                        onClick={() => {this.props.flip({x: i, y: n})}}
                        disabled={this.props.isEnding}
                    >&nbsp;</button>
                )
            }
            array.push(
                <div className="boardRow" align="center">
                    {row_}
                </div>
            );
            // key++;
        }
        return (
            <div>{array}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I can confirm that all functions and values I called from `this.props` are correct.

For some reason, the rendered `button`s doesn't have any `onClick` attribute upon inspecting with Chromium Developer Tools.

Any ideas?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you trigger the flip function or not? If you can, chrome just doesn't display the onclick attribute but still get it bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly normal for the button elements rendered by React to not have an *onclick* attribute. There are more efficient ways to add an event handler than an *onclick* attribute, namely using the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method, which is what React does behind the scenes.

I've put your code example in a sandbox to try it out, it works just fine, the *flip* function is called when one of the buttons is clicked:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vq1912yxr5